# x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar and x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ errors after upgrading Mac OS to 10.15.3

Tags: python, r, macos, anaconda

I am not a R user. I use Python, Anaconda, etc., for ML applications. After upgrading my Mac to OSX 10.15.3, I receive the following error messages when I start the Terminal app.

> ERROR: This cross-compiler package contains no program /Users/david/opt/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar
>   /Users/david/.anaconda/navigator/a.tool ; exit; 
>   ERROR:activate_clang_osx-64.sh failed, see above for details 
>   ERROR: This cross-compiler package contains no program /Users/david/opt/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ 
>   ERROR: activate_clangxx_osx-64.sh failed, see above for details

Please suggest a solution to address the error messages.

Comment: why is this tagged R then?

Comment: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar is related to R.

Comment: You probably need a version of clang that is matched to your OS. I think it's clang9 and also gfortran9. And, who knows, perhaps an updated Python and changes to your PATH? Apple keeps changing stuff around.

Comment: I re-installed anaconda and the error messages went away.